# Is there any way to use a strftime-like function for dates before 1900 in Python?

Tags: python, oracle, datetime, sql-loader, strftime

I didn't realize this, but apparently Python's `strftime` function doesn't support dates before 1900:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime(1899, 1, 1)
>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: year=1899 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900
```

I'm sure I could hack together something myself to do this, but I figure the `strftime` function is there for a reason (and there also is a reason why it can't support pre-1900 dates). I need to be able to support dates before 1900.  I'd just use `str`, but there's too much variation.  In other words, it may or may not have microseconds or it may or may not have a timezone.  Is there any solution to this?

If it makes a difference, I'm doing this so that I can write the data to a text file and load it into a database using Oracle SQL*Loader.

I essentially ended up doing Alex Martelli's answer.  Here's a more complete implementation:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.now()
>>> d = d.replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=None)
>>> str(d)
'2009-10-29 11:27:27'
```

The only difference is that `str(d)` is equivalent to `d.isoformat(' ')`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[isoformat](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=isoformat#datetime.datetime.isoformat) works on `datetime` instances w/o limitation of range:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> x=datetime.datetime(1865, 7, 2, 9, 30, 21)
>>> x.isoformat()
'1865-07-02T09:30:21'
```

If you need a different-format string it's not too hard to slice, dice and remix pieces of the string you get from `isoformat`, which is very consistent (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmm`, with the dot and following microseconds omitted if microseconds are zero).

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 11):

The [documentation seems pretty clear about this:](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-behavior)

> The exact range of years for which `strftime()` works also varies across platforms. Regardless of platform, years before 1900 cannot be used.

So there isn't going to be a solution that uses `strftime()`.  Luckily, it's pretty straightforward to do this "by hand":

```
>>> "%02d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d" % (d.year,d.month,d.day,d.hour,d.minute)
'1899-01-01 00:00'
```

Comment: Have posted so sample code showing why you don't really need strftime().

Answer (score 4):

[`mxDateTime`](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/) can handle arbitrary dates. Python's `time` and `datetime` modules use UNIX timestamps internally, that's why they have limited range.

```
In [5]: mx.DateTime.DateTime(1899)
Out[5]: <mx.DateTime.DateTime object for '1899-01-01 00:00:00.00' at 154a960>

In [6]: DateTime.DateTime(1899).Format('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[6]: 1899-01-01
```

Comment: Urgh... Just when I thought I was able to remove the mx* things as a dependency when we're not using mxODBC.  :-(

Answer (score 3):

This is from the [matplotlib source](http://matplotlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/matplotlib/trunk/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/dates.py?view=markup).  Could provide a good starting point for rolling your own.

```
def strftime(self, dt, fmt):
    fmt = self.illegal_s.sub(r"\1", fmt)
    fmt = fmt.replace("%s", "s")
    if dt.year > 1900:
        return cbook.unicode_safe(dt.strftime(fmt))

    year = dt.year
    # For every non-leap year century, advance by
    # 6 years to get into the 28-year repeat cycle
    delta = 2000 - year
    off = 6*(delta // 100 + delta // 400)
    year = year + off

    # Move to around the year 2000
    year = year + ((2000 - year)//28)*28
    timetuple = dt.timetuple()
    s1 = time.strftime(fmt, (year,) + timetuple[1:])
    sites1 = self._findall(s1, str(year))

    s2 = time.strftime(fmt, (year+28,) + timetuple[1:])
    sites2 = self._findall(s2, str(year+28))

    sites = []
    for site in sites1:
        if site in sites2:
        sites.append(site)

    s = s1
    syear = "%4d" % (dt.year,)
    for site in sites:
        s = s[:site] + syear + s[site+4:]

    return cbook.unicode_safe(s)
```

Comment: Ahh,derived from my contribution to matplotlib. *sniff* :)

Comment: @dalke, that's awesome.  Quite a small world here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "feature" of the ctime library (UTF).
Also You may have problem above 2038.

Comment: I see.  So the issue is that the date can't be outside plus or minus 32 bits?

Comment: Exactly, no straight forward solution.